# Как вызвать метод контроллера с параметром через ActionLink?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Я хочу отобразить пост через отдельную функцию Post:

```
public ActionResult Post(Guid postId)
{
    MagentaEntities context = new MagentaEntities();

    var post = context.Post.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == postId);
    ViewBag.Post = post;

    return View("~/Views/Forum/Post.cshtml");
}
```

Но после генерации списка постов с помощью ActionLink() при переходе входящий Guid оказывается пустым.

Код генерации с помощью ActionLink():

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> item in postsToHeaders)
{
    <div>@Html.ActionLink(item.Value, "Post", new { id = item.Key })</div>
}
```

как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Post(Guid id)
```

или

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink(item.Value, "Post", new { postId = item.Key })</div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! Плюсик вам в карму!

Comment: @Alkanores Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.